# How to add ng-if directive in a tab header for different screen resolutions

Tags: angularjs, html, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-4

Friends after researching, I appeal to you so that you can help me with this problem that is currently being presented to me. I am working with tabset and I need to add a ternary operator, which fulfills the following condition: If the screen resolution is greater than 480px, the text acquired from a database (text: "CREDIT LINE") must be shown, but if is less than 480px should only say: "SOLES"

I'm trying the following:

```
<bcp-tab heading = "{{windowWidth> 480? 'CREDIT_LINE_SOLES': 'Soles'}}" background-tab = "''">
```

But I do not get what I want since it is taking the value of the variable ('CREDIT_LINE_SOLES') and not the database, but the value of 'soles' works correctly the ternary operator could tell me how it should be that operator ternary within heading of the tab? I would greatly appreciate your cooperation.

Comment: You need to show the controller where windowWidth is set?

Comment: I need to use ng-translate in that ternary operated